# $S_n$ acting on set of natural numbers

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

When it's said that the group of permutations $S_n$ acts on $A=\{1,...,n\}$, how does an element $\sigma_i \in S_n$ act on a single element $a \in A$? In other word, how does a permutation of numbers from $A$ actually act on a single natural number from $A$? I think I got confused conceptually.

Comment: My idea is that for a permutation $\sigma = (1259)$, $a=2$, $\sigma(2) = 5$. Would this be correct?

Comment: I think the group $S_{n}$ really is a group of functions and as so, they are these abstract objects that we "cannot see". When we imagine then moving things around, we are imaging exactly the group action. So it is acting in $a\in A$ by applying the permutation $\sigma$ to it. Someone correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

If $n=4$ the permutation $(1,2,3)$ acts on $1$ by sending it to $2$, it acts on $4$ by sending it to $4$.